# Render different static folder based on url request

Tags: static, flask

Using Flask, I can render different templates based on the url. For example :

- http://example.com/site1/ ; will render templates/site1/{htmls}
- http://example.com/site2/ ; will render templates/site2/{htmls}

This works really great with jinja_loader and a custom Loader, but now I'm stuck with the static files.

The static files depends on the template, so they are located in templates/static/site{0-9}, but of course, I cannot set a jinja_loader on the static_folder parameter because it's not related to Jinja but to Flask.

How can I render the correct static folder based on the current URL?

As an example, here's the loaded code:

```
Flask(app_name,
        static_url_path = '/public',
        static_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates/static')
    )
```

and in templates/static, I have :

```
static/
    site1/
        css/
        js/
        images/
    site2/
        css/
        js/
        images/
    etc...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you provide some URLs and how they should map to actual files?

Comment: I updated the question, does it helps more ?

Comment: And your templates are using `url_for('static', 'site1/css/...')`, etc. to generate the correct URLs already? What is the exact problem here?

Comment: No, my templates uses `{{url_for('static', filename='css/...')}}`. Ideally, I would modify where Flask search for the static files when rendering `/public/css/...`, to search not in `/templates/static/css/...`, but in `/templates/static/site1/css/...`

Comment: You'll need to produce your own `static` view handler then.

Comment: Interesting, any pointer on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other interesting alternative is the following :

```
class GenericStaticFlask(Flask):
    def send_static_file(self, filename):
        # g.site contains the name of the template path for siteX
        return super(GenericStaticFlask, self).send_static_file("%s/%s" % (g.site, filename))

app = GenericStaticFlask(app_name,
    static_url_path = '/public',
    static_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates/static')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You either have to use explicit paths in your `static` views:

```
url_for('static', filename='site1/css/...')
```

where `site1` could be taken from `request.path.split('/', 1)[0]`:

```
url_for('static', filename='{}/css/...'.format(request.path.split('/', 1)[0]))
```

You could create a custom `static` view:

```
from flask import request, send_from_directory, current_app, safe_join
import os.path

@app.route('/<site>/static/<path:filename>')
def per_site_static(site, filename):
    if site is None:
        # pick site from the URL; only works if there is a `/site/` first element.
        site = request.path.split('/')[0]
    static_folder = safe_join(current_app.static_folder, site)
    cache_timeout = current_app.get_send_file_max_age(filename)
    return send_from_directory(static_folder, filename,
                               cache_timeout=cache_timeout)
```

Then use `url_for()` to generate urls:

```
{{ url_for('per_site_static', site=None, filename='css/...') }}
```